# How to pass count to U-SQL Applier?

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to pass data count to custom applier but I am not sure how to pass it. Here is my sample code where I am calculating count in @count and passing it to CsvApplier constructor but it is not working. Is there any way to achieve this in U-SQL?

Note that it is not working so I am looking

```
DECLARE @in string = "/input/abc.csv";
DECLARE @out string = "/output/xyz.csv";

@selectlog =
    EXTRACT UserId string,                
            StartTime string,
            EndTime string,            
    FROM @in
    USING Extractors.Csv(silent:true);

@count =
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM @selectlog;

@log =
    SELECT t.UserId,
           t.StartTime,
           t.EndTime,
    FROM @selectlog
         CROSS APPLY new DemoJobs.CsvApplier(@count) AS t(UserId string, StartTime string, EndTime string);


OUTPUT @log
TO @out
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false);
```

Comment: removed comment and put it into answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that @count is of type `TABLE(count long?)` and U-SQL does not give you scalar variable assignment or table passing to a C# function, since that would require us to introduce a synchronization point in the execution graph.

To get what you want, you could do a CROSS JOIN between `@selectlog` and `@count` to add the count to every row and then apply the Applier. Or you could do a custom REDUCER.

Comment: Thanks, CROSS JOIN did the job.